# Error when attempting to find_if() when the string starts with a value that is NOT alphanumeric

Tags: c++, string

I'm making a bit of code that removes punctuation from a string. Any punctuation in the start is to be skipped, and any throughout the rest of the string if punctuation is found it would stop before that.

So I have two iterators `i` and `x`.

My goal is for `i` to be a pointer to the first alphanumeric character and `x` to be a pointer to the last alphanumeric character (I.E. before the first NON-alphanumeric character).

Examples of how I want it to work:

```
input string is JOHN_DOE
the output would be john
input string is John'doe
the output would be john
the input would be "John_Doe
the output would be john
```

The problem I am running into is every time I input the first character of the string with a value that is NOT alphanumeric, I get a `std::length_error`. Otherwise, if the first character is alphanumeric, it works how I want it to.

I am trying to implement this using `find_if()` from the standard library. Any advice or tips would be much appreciated.

Code below:

```
int main()
{

    std::string before;
    std::cin >> before;

    std::string::iterator i = std::find_if(before.begin(), before.end(), ischar);
    std::string::iterator x = std::find_if(before.begin(), before.end(), isNchar);

    std::string after(i, x);

    std::for_each(after.begin(), after.end(), makeLow);

    std::cout << "Before: " << before;
    std::cout << "\nAfter: " << after;
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}

// Utility functions below
//-------------------------------------------
bool ischar(char i)
{
    return std::isalnum(static_cast<unsigned char>(i));
}

bool isNchar(char i)
{
    return !(std::isalnum(static_cast<unsigned char>(i)));
}

void makeLow(char& i)
{
    i = tolower(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not test `i` and `x`. It can cause `std::string after(before.end(), before.begin());`. In other words, when the first char is not alphanum, `x` gets `before.begin()` and `i` gets something after `before.begin()`.

According to your description you want

```
std::string::iterator i = std::find_if(before.begin(), before.end(), ischar);
std::string::iterator x = std::find_if(i, before.end(), isNchar);

std::string after(i, x);
```

Comment: Very great point I was overlooking! Thank you very much!